# How to design a 2-level fractional factorial experiment given some prior knowledge

Tags: experiment-design, fractional-factorial

We're designing a trial to test four factors (call them `A`, `B`, `C` and `D`) for an experiment. Each factor has two levels: `+` and `-`. The `+` of factor `A` is believed to lead to better results and the `-` of factor `B` is also believed to lead to better results. We know nothing about `C` and `D`, nor whether any interaction effects exist or not.

We want to get the following goals:

1. Find the combination of factors to get the best result.
2. Build a model containing `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` to predict the result of experiments. (This requires that `A` and `B` should still be in this design)

How can we get a fractional factorial design based on our prior knowledge of the effects of `A` and `B`?